# how to zoom in/out with button click images

Tags: android, image, pinchzoom

I am new to android. I am working on project in which I have an image view and 2 buttons and 10 images in drawable. With button cliks images are changing perfectly but I dont know how to zoom these images. I applied most of the methods of pinch zoom in it but remained unsuccessful. Plz help with code.Especially in main java.

Main java

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Private ImageView hImageViewPic;
Private Button iButton, gButton;
Private int currentImage=0;
Int images []={R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,//and so on}
@Override
Protected void onCreat (bundle savedInstanceState){
Super.onCreat (SavedInstanceState);
SetContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
Intent i=getIntent ();
Int position=i.getExtras ().getInt ("id");
hImageViewPic=(ImageView) findViewById (R.id.idImageViewPic);
iButton=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bIleri);
gButton=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bGeri);
iButton.setOnClickListener (i ButtonChangeImageListener);
gButton.setOnClickListener (gButtonChangeImageListener);
}
View.onClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener=new onClickListener (){
Public void onClick (View v){
currentImage++;
currentImage=currentImage%images.length;
hImageViewPic.setImageResource (images [currentImage]);
}
};
View.onClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener=new OnClickListener (){
Public void onClick (View v){
currentImage--;
currentImage=(currntImage+images.length)% images.length;
hImageViewPic.setImageResource (images [currentImage]);
}
};
}
```

Main xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="100"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="#66FFFF"
android:maxHeight="91dip"
android:maxWidth="47dip"
android:padding="10dip"
android:src="@drawable/a0"/>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
android:id="@+id/bGeri"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="back">
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/bIleri"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Next">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below custom class for ImageView.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static int NONE = 0;
static int DRAG = 1;
static int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 0.5f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;


int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;


ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}
public void resetView() {

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    NONE = 0;
    DRAG = 1;
    ZOOM = 2;
    mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    last = new PointF();
    start = new PointF();
    minScale = 0.5f;
    maxScale = 3f;
    CLICK = 3;
    saveScale = 1f;

    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}
private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanx sir. But what I have to write down in main java. I mean which code.

Comment: Use below code for ImageView in your xml : `<com.example.customviews.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/a0"/>`

Comment: It's my pleasure to share knowledge. :)

Comment: Sir can u plz tell me how to set as wallpaper these images. Thanx

Comment: @UrMi can u please help me how can i write code to zoom image on button click with specific scale and as well as zoom out

Comment: this is the tutorial i m following http://asmncl.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-zoominzoomout-imageview.html?showComment=1390490924149

Comment: this is question please see the last comment and give your code if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312718/failed-to-display-zoom-image-and-other-contents-on-same-ui-in-android