# Failed to display zoom image and other contents on same UI in Android?

Tags: android, xml, zooming

i am newbie in android can someone please help me,i am following this tutorial [ZOOM IMAGEVIEW CLASS](http://asmncl.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-zoominzoomout-imageview.html?showComment=1390490924149)
my problem is that i want to click on an imageview on clicking it will move to next activity that will show previous clicked activity zoom image in upper part and rest of contents in rest of the part but right now i am failed to load my XML file here by using this tutorial.Its just zooming the image

Code here:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample); // i want to show this layout how can i show zoom image in this layout.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String stringData = intent.getStringExtra("imageName");//this is image file name
    Log.i("stringData",""+stringData);

    String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+stringData , null, null);
    System.out.println("IMG ID :: "+imgId);
    System.out.println("PACKAGE_NAME :: "+PACKAGE_NAME);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId);
     TouchImageView touch = new TouchImageView(this);
    touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f

    //ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    //image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    setContentView(touch);
}
```

Here is the Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_ask_fatwa_one" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_email_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/email"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_share_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/share_fatwa"
        android:layout_weight="1"/> 
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/save_fatwa"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    

    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the touch view ? Inside your simple xml file or overlaying your simple.xml file ?

Comment: it should be before this Linear layout <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

Comment: Please share the package name , where the file `TouchImageView` is located in your Project. and what height and width should this `TouchImageView` should occupy on the screen ?

Comment: TouchImageView is same as i copied from url mentioned and in the same package:                 package com.example.zoomimagesample;   both files TouchImageView    and MainActivity are in the same package

Comment: can u please let me know where should i need to mention the width and height of TouchImageView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45928/discussion-between-salman-ayub-and-erum-hannan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `setContentView(touch);` that is hiding your previously setup of `setContentView(R.layout.sample);` 
All you need do is to put this `TouchImageView` in your `sample.xml` Layout file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_ask_fatwa_one" />

   <com.example.zoomimagesample.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_DESIRED_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="OUR_DESIRED_HEIGHT"
         />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/btn_email_fatwa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/email"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>    
 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/btn_share_fatwa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/share_fatwa"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/btn_save_fatwa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/save_fatwa"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

And edit your `onCreate(...)` method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sample); // i want to show this layout how can i show zoom image in this layout.
Intent intent = getIntent();
String stringData = intent.getStringExtra("imageName");//this is image file name
Log.i("stringData",""+stringData);

String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+stringData , null, null);
System.out.println("IMG ID :: "+imgId);
System.out.println("PACKAGE_NAME :: "+PACKAGE_NAME);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId);
TouchImageView touch = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.ID_THAT_YOU_ASSIGNED_TO_THE_TOUCH_IMAGE)VIEW);
touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f

//ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
//image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//setContentView(touch);
}
```

**EDIT :**  
You are missing the constructors that is used to invoke your View via XML:

Here add these two constructors:

```
public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   super.setClickable(true);
   this.context = context;
   mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
   matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
   m = new float[9];
   setImageMatrix(matrix);
   setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

   setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

           matrix.getValues(m);
           float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
           float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
           PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

           switch (event.getAction()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   start.set(last);
                   mode = DRAG;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                   last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   start.set(last);
                   mode = ZOOM;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale)) {
                       Log.d("******", "ZOOM OR DRAG");
                       float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                       float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                       float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                       float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                       if (scaleWidth < width) {
                           deltaX = 0;
                           if (y + deltaY > 0)
                               deltaY = -y;
                           else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                               deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                       } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                           deltaY = 0;
                           if (x + deltaX > 0)
                               deltaX = -x;
                           else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                               deltaX = -(x + right);
                       } else {
                           if (x + deltaX > 0)
                               deltaX = -x;
                           else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                               deltaX = -(x + right);

                           if (y + deltaY > 0)
                               deltaY = -y;
                           else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                               deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                       }
                       matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                       last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                   }else if(mode == DRAG && saveScale == minScale) {
                       Log.d("******", "DRAG");
                   }
                   break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   mode = NONE;
                   int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                   int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                   if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                       performClick();
                   break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                   mode = NONE;
                   break;
           }
           setImageMatrix(matrix);
           invalidate();
           return true; // indicate event was handled
       }

   });
  }

  public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   super.setClickable(true);
   this.context = context;
   mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
   matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
   m = new float[9];
   setImageMatrix(matrix);
   setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

   setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

           matrix.getValues(m);
           float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
           float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
           PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

           switch (event.getAction()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   start.set(last);
                   mode = DRAG;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                   last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   start.set(last);
                   mode = ZOOM;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale)) {
                       Log.d("******", "ZOOM OR DRAG");
                       float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                       float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                       float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                       float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                       if (scaleWidth < width) {
                           deltaX = 0;
                           if (y + deltaY > 0)
                               deltaY = -y;
                           else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                               deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                       } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                           deltaY = 0;
                           if (x + deltaX > 0)
                               deltaX = -x;
                           else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                               deltaX = -(x + right);
                       } else {
                           if (x + deltaX > 0)
                               deltaX = -x;
                           else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                               deltaX = -(x + right);

                           if (y + deltaY > 0)
                               deltaY = -y;
                           else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                               deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                       }
                       matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                       last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                   }else if(mode == DRAG && saveScale == minScale) {
                       Log.d("******", "DRAG");
                   }
                   break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   mode = NONE;
                   int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                   int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                   if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                       performClick();
                   break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                   mode = NONE;
                   break;
           }
           setImageMatrix(matrix);
           invalidate();
           return true; // indicate event was handled
       }

   });
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: CAN U PLEASE help me how can i edit this code for zoom in and zoom out on button click

Comment: Sure, you can add the scale factor when clicked on `+` button and subtract the scale factor when clicked on `-` button from the TouchImageView's current scale factor.

Comment: can you please give me an example i m facing difficulty to do this ......please update your code

Comment: I will answer you in a while.

Comment: please answer here if possible

Comment: Hey, i have implemented this functionality and uploaded it. Download it using this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8vsb6kf21rm5ng/ImageTouchView%20-%20Salman%20Ayub.zip

Comment: Please check this answer too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414345/zoom-in-out-image-on-button-click-in-android/21416197#21416197

Comment: i have checked this code roughly in emulator and its working fine i am pretty sure that it will work in device as well thanks a lot U r king

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46283/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-salman-ayub)

Comment: can u please help me how can i adjust my zoomImageView in center and fixed header and footer as well i have made xml but its not giving me accurate result

Comment: Sure, i am in office right now. I will see through this problem as i come back.

Comment: can u please load my xml and adjust the image same as u did in your xml and also zoom in and out btn will be closed to eachother

Comment: Please upload the complete project, so that i can atleast see the proper xml loaded in my GUI editor.

Comment: i have uploaded it pls check the complete project

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86719018/ImageTouchView%20-%20Salman%20Ayubwithnewxml.rar

Comment: Please tell me, how the Layout should exactly look. You can draw it in Paint and send me that demonstrated layout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46487/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-salman-ayub)