# LinearLayout Buttons not appearing when device orientation changed to Horizontal?

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is the xml in which ScrollView layout size will vary means it will zoom image on button click but my top headers and footer will always be in same position irrespective of zoom values.......

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_zoom_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/btn_zoomIn"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"

          android:src="@drawable/zoomin1" />
       <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/btn_zoomout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/zoomin1" />


     </LinearLayout>  
     <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
          <com.example.imagetouchview.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagezoom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"> 
           </com.example.imagetouchview.TouchImageView>     
            </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_email_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/zoomin1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_share_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/zoomin1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/> 
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_fatwa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/zoomin1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    


    </LinearLayout>    


</LinearLayout>
```

this layout is fine in vertical orientation while when device orientatio changes to Horizontal the bottom buttons are invisible.I am following [Salmans Ayub Answer For Image Zoomin and Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312718/failed-to-display-zoom-image-and-other-contents-on-same-ui-in-android/21313597?noredirect=1#comment32369302_21313597)

Answer (score 1):

I think You have design your layout in portrait mode(verticaly). Now either you have to bound it for 
portrait mode by adding this line  android:screenOrientation="portrait" in your activity manifest,

OR

You have to design it for landscape mode by following this link-
[Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode)

Comment: i need both orientations can u please edit my code to work in both orientation

Comment: you have to design it in both orientation as i given the link follow that. and accept the ans if get solved

Comment: create a new folder layout-land, in resourses folder copy YOUR.xml into it and design accordingl in view.

Comment: on device orientation it will automatically load horizontal xml or may i need to define explicitly

Comment: on devices it will take automatically as you are facing .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46422/discussion-between-user3233280-and-lucky)