# android studio zoom image in + horizontal scrolling

Tags: android

I am working on an android project, and for that I have a human model image:

[image]

I would like to zoom right in, so that you can only see one human model e.g. the middle one to start with, then have 2 arrows on either side of the image, and click left arrow to see the left human model, and right to see the right human model.

This is my attempt, but doesn't work

**layout activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_page"
tools:context="com.example.lahirufernando.skinsensor.HomePage"
android:background="#e0e0e0">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/peace" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbox" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/left_arrow" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/questionBtn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/questionBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/right_arrow" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ibLeft"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ibRight"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/humanbody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@null" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFF"
    android:text="Tip: You can zoom in and turn your device!"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/questionBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bodyPart"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFF"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/question" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bodyPart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Click a Body Region"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

**activity:**

```
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
HorizontalScrollView hSV;
Button ibLeft,ibRight;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    FloatingActionButton homeBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    FloatingActionButton questionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.questionBtn);
    hSV = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);

    ibLeft=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ibLeft);
    ibLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hSV.scrollTo((int)hSV.getScrollX() - 10, (int)hSV.getScrollY());
        }
    });

    ibRight=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ibRight);
    ibLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hSV.scrollTo((int)hSV.getScrollX() + 10, (int)hSV.getScrollY());
        }
    });



    // Add image
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.human);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to zoom in/out with button click images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211130/how-to-zoom-in-out-with-button-click-images)